# dovecot copy emails to one account

Tags: dovecot

I have a number of email accounts I wish to "merge" - They are on the same dovecot server - is it as simple as copying the cur folders contents (the email files) to the account I wish to have them in or is there another process which considers the account database?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the easiest solution. But you can use dovecot sync too.

More info about that:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync

Answer (score 1):

**cur** folder implies that's you're using Maildir type format. Thus, copying the files will suffice.